How do I make my amplitude demodulated signal useful for further use?
I am simulating amplitude modulation and demodulation and then later using the demodulated signal to drive a speaker
I use a simple diode circuit to modulate and demodulate the signal:

Modulated signal:



Demodulated signal

Original input signal post active lowpass filter
I am quite happy with the demodulation results.  I think this good, but there are two issues with the signal

It seems offset from the zero.  I would like it to be oscillating around the zero so it can be properly amplified and drive the speaker.
There still seems to be a high frequency component with my signal which I can't remove with a high pass filter. In fact, the signal seems completely unfazed by the high pass filter I have after the demodulator. The signasl are identical before and after including  there frequency spectrums

What could I do to achieve my required characteristics for this signal?

You need a low pass filter to get rid of high frequency components.

@JRE cant believe i didnt notice this, thank you for pointing it out

An unrelated comment:
Since R28, R29 (100 ohms) have no square-blue connection dots, they are superfluous.
Your requirement wants no offset (average value of zero). Since demodulator C12 blocks DC, it will perform this function. However the time constant RC of about one second takes a long time to decay, so the 5ms span of that transient run is too short to see that eventually, the audio waveform decays toward average of zero.
The time constant in effect is C12 * R27. C12 could be made much smaller, and stil have audio down to say, 20 Hz.
Another requirement is near-elimination of carrier frequency (and harmonics).
This involves mostly another time constant: (R26 + R30)*C11. This is a low-pass filter which should pass audio, but suppress 1.85 MHz.
You'd want \${1}\over{\omega\times RC}\$ to be around 15kHz...the upper limit of audio. Using such low value of R as 32 ohms makes the diode peak current quite high...this resistance could be increased. If you need the detector output to drive low-impedance audio, add an active audio buffer stage.

Another point. Driving the diode detector with a zero-ohm voltage source is unrealistic. The radio frequency amplifier that drives this detector will likely have a higher resistance. Adding a series resistance before the diode will make detection more difficult, but more realistic.
LTspice seems to be simulating. A very nice built-in distortionless modulator is available, like this:

 D1, R1, C1 are the basic components of the AM demodulator. I have added R3 (250 ohms) to simulate a source resistance for a bit more realism.
